# Implementing underlined typing effect similar to slack home page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to mimic the typing effect similar to [slack homepage](https://slack.com/). It makes use of [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/), and I also used the same.

But how that underline and exclamation mark effect is implemented? Can anyone please give any suggestions or tutorial/code snippet. Thanks.

My html :

```
<div class="message"></div>
```

and the javascript :

```
$(function(){
      $(".message").typed({
        strings: ["This is the first line^1500", "This is the second line"],
        startDelay: 1500,
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500
      });
  });
```

PS : I am a beginner in CSS

Comment: They used an SVG line (you can create with a vector graphics software) which shows up under the words (wrapped in span) after the typedjs animation is finished. The lines are animated using CSS keyframes that modify the stroke-offset of SVG path. The exclamation part is pretty easy and works same way.

Comment: Aziz : Wow!!! SVGs can be animated as well? I never thought that. Thanks, I will explore more into this.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a bit and composed a little example on JSBin. Press "Run with JS" to see it in action. You can play with this too, just try to change some values!

http://jsbin.com/cihaxuzire/edit?html,css,output

SVG and CSS are copied directly from the slack website.

There is a great article about that:
https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Hope this helps.